# i18n translate vocabulary field description

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I want to localise vocabulary fields especially description field. Does it exist some function like `i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms( taxonomy_term_load($tid)` for `taxonomy_vocabulary_load($vid)`. Or maybe some different method.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the taxonomy translation module in i18n module? I think that will do the job!

Comment: yes i translated e.g. vocabulary description via that module but how to invoke on other languages

Answer (score 1):

You can localize the taxonomy description field out-of-the-box with the [Entity Translation](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.  While Entity Translation can be used in combination with the i18n suite of modules, note that **you cannot use Entity Translation for taxonomy in conjunction with the i18n Taxonomy translation module; you must select one or the other.**

If you use Entity Translation, to translate the taxonomy term names you will also need the [Title](https://drupal.org/project/title) module.

Comment: So i have to install module just for one sentence :/ rather i will make some sql query or something

Comment: @Nikola I just saw your comment that you already translated the strings using i18n taxonomy.  I will leave my answer for people wanting to do this from scratch, but in your specific case you simply need to add support for i18n to the module that is not displaying the strings properly.

Answer (score 1):

I made simple function. I don't know is it properly but it do job for me. Where $lid Unique identifier of this string, you can find it on page  Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface, edit link.

```
function t_lid($lid,$lang){    
    $translation=db_query('SELECT l.translation FROM {locales_target} l WHERE l.lid = :lid AND l.language=:lang', array(':lid' => $lid,':lang'=>$lang))->fetchField();
        return $translation;
    }
```

I hate to install module for one simple thing :)